# Omitting half of a letter in Japanese

Tags: pronunciation, katakana, loanwords, pitch-accent

Specifically when transcribing foreign words into katakana, it is often implied that half of a letter is dropped in pronunciation.

Take for example メルボルン, the Japanese import of the Australian city name Melbourne. The rōmaji for this is *Meruborun*. However, it is pronounced *Merborn*. Therefore, the latter half of *ru* is intuitively dropped in both of its instances within the word.

Is there a symbol which denotes that only the first half of the preceding character should be used? Or is the conversion between orthoëpy and lexicon usually intuitive?

Comment: "However, it is pronounced Merborn" ← by who? メルボルン is always pronounced by Japanese speakers as me-ru-bo-ru-n, character-by-character, as a five-[mora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_(Japanese_prosody)) word. Nothing is omitted, although English speakers may feel some unnecessary sounds are *inserted* in the Japanese version of Melbourne.

Comment: Oh, okay. So Japanese speakers would say things like "Vegemaito"?

Comment: They would say something roughly like "bejimaito"  (https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%99%E3%82%B8%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88). `he justo smairudo ando gebu me a bejimaito sandowichu`

Comment: Why, when they have the sound 'v'? (I.e. 'u' with a 'ten-ten'.) @virmaior

Comment: @MadBanners ヴ exists in part for marking foreign words that contain v. Not all speakers pronounce them differently.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4 , http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1099654090 , https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4

Comment: @MadBanners: I left Japan in 2005, so I'm less familiar with trends among younger speakers, but in my admittedly dated experience, the only Japanese speakers I knew who could pronounce the English ⟨ v ⟩ sound were those with extensive experience living in English-speaking areas.  And even then, they'd (usually) pronounce it as //b// when speaking Japanese.  Might be a bit like English speakers who pronounce "Paris" as //pa.ʁi// instead of //ˈpɛɹ.ɪs// -- it might come off as pretentious in the wrong social context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loanwords are pronounced exactly the way they are transcribed. Depending on the circumstances of the transcription (which are often unknown), the transcription is based on a mix of actual pronunciation, its alphabet representation and the weather.

If "Melbourne" becomes メルボルン, then it will be pronounced exactly like //meruboruɴ//, no matter whether it's far from or close to the original pronunciation. (It could also have been メルボーン.)

<sub>The insertion of the extra vowels follows some loose rules: the default is *u*. However since *t*+*u* becomes [[tsu]], after *t* you usually use *o* instead of *u*, as in アート *āto* "art". However this may be broken if *tsu* is perceived to be a similarly good fit, e.g. ピーナツ *pīnatsu* "peanut" or "peanut**s**". Sometimes the choice is also just taken to be  the same  as the vowel that follows it: for example in a syllable with two consonants and the vowel *i*, the default *u* that would be "inserted" after the first consonant may also become *i*, to avoid the contrast *–u–i*, as in キリスト *k**i**risuto* "Christ".</sub>

There have been efforts to include phonemes from other languages, such as //va vi vu ve vo//, transcribed as ヴァ ヴィ ヴ ヴェ ヴォ, but by many still pronounced [[ba bi bu be bo]]. (For example, ヴィオラ vs. ビオラ. Also see [Do Japanese actually pronounce the "v" sound?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24498/1628))

The introduction of スィ ([[si]] rather than [[ɕi]]) or ディ ([[di]] rather than [[dʑi]]) has been successful. For example, older sources use エジンバラ *Ejinbara* for Edinburgh, but エディンバラ *Edinbara* now seems to be standard and most people do pronounce ディ as [[di]].

Having to introduce extra vowels into loanwords, like *Mer**u**bor**u**n* can lead to curious effects when actually pronounced. For example プロ from "pro(fessional)" has pitch accent プロ【HL】, which sounds like the first vowel in *p**u**ro* (which shouldn't be there) is stressed.

So, unlike in English (or French), in Japanese everything that is written is pronounced — sometimes even with a pitch accent that sounds like vowels which weren't present in the original word are stressed.

Comment: Great answer @Earthliŋ. As for the pronunciation of your username, well played :)