# 'V' sound in Japanese

Tags: sound-symbolism

How do I get a V sound in Japanese?
How do I write my name XAVIER

Thank you in advance for your reply.
Prasanna XD

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24498/1628

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Japanese actually pronounce the "v" sound?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24498/do-japanese-actually-pronounce-the-v-sound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We Japanese all know your name [here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B6%E3%83%93%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB) (in Japanese) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Xavier) (in English).

We usually write Xavier as ザビエル, but the Japanese who could write it as ザヴィエル have increased since English loanwords have increased.
The sound of ビ is *bi*, while ヴィ is *vi*, so ヴィ seems to express the sound  more accurately.

But, we are familiar with フランシスコ ザビエル, so I recommend you to write your name as ザビエル.