# What's my name in Japanese - Sensei can't pronounce it

Tags: translation

I moved to a different country and joined a new karate club. Sensei speaks only Japanese and I'm ok with the commands he gives, but the ridiculous situation is that he can't pronounce my name (Povilas).

It became a comic problem when he names everyone - Tom, Ann, Patrick, etc., but I'm left alone and he just points at me and asks - "What's your name again?".

How would "Povilas" sound in Japanese? Maybe there's a similar sounding word or combination of two words?

Help is very much appreciated - I just want him to know who I am.

Comment: Keep in mind that people that speak languages other than Japanese also have this problem as well. It does not seem intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found one famous person has the same name as you in Japanese Wikipedia.

"Povilas Vanagas", a Lithuanian ice dancer, is translated as [「ポヴィラス・ヴァナガス」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9D%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A1%E3%83%8A%E3%82%AC%E3%82%B9) .

Japanese don't distinguish [l] and [r] , [b] and [v]. It might be difficult for your karate sensei to catch and distinguish the sounds of your name by their ear at first time.

If you accept *Povilas* as「ポヴィラス」to be spelt in Japanese, I assume one of the explanation to pronounce it like:

"***Po***" as "Pokémon" : 「**ポ**ケモン」

"***vi***" as "Venus" : 「**ヴィ**ーナス」

"***las***" as "Last" : 「**ラス**ト」or "Las Vegas" 「**ラス**べガス」.

Use the bold part and concatenate altogether to pronounce your name. I hope it works.

I remember it was very difficult for me to pronounce "Woolworths", supermarkets in Australia. I pronounced "Wool" +  "Worths" very slowly and tried to pronounce them at once. I recommend you ask him to pronounce your name very slowly at first.

There are questions discussed about the difficulties for Japanese to distinguish those sounds:

[Do Japanese actually pronounce the "v" sound?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24498/do-japanese-actually-pronounce-the-v-sound)

[Why do Japanese speakers have difficulty pronouncing "L"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/why-do-japanese-speakers-have-difficulty-pronouncing-l/9327#9327)